# C# Console: System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed:

Tags: c#, asp.net, httpwebrequest, system.net.httpwebrequest

I am trying to call `httpWebRequest` from c# console application. keep getting  `System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed:`. I have searched Stackoverflow questions and google non helped me.

If I paste url on browser its working fine and getting json file back but from code it is not working. Is something doing in the code?

```
     Console.WriteLine("url: " + url);
        string urlGlobal = url + email;
        urlGlobal = urlGlobal + "?optout_value=0";
        Console.WriteLine("urlGlobal: " + urlGlobal);
        request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(urlGlobal);
        Console.WriteLine("After WebRequest.Create");
        request.Method = "GET";
        request.ContentType = "application/json";
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls;

        Console.WriteLine("After TLS");
        response = request.GetResponse();
```

exception:

```
    Unhandled Exception: System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive. ---> System.ComponentModel
server cannot communicate, because they do not possess a common algorithm
   at System.Net.SSPIWrapper.AcquireCredentialsHandle(SSPIInterface SecModule, String package, CredentialUse intent, SecureCredential scc)
   at System.Net.Security.SecureChannel.AcquireCredentialsHandle(CredentialUse credUsage, SecureCredential& secureCredential)
   at System.Net.Security.SecureChannel.AcquireClientCredentials(Byte[]& thumbPrint)
   at System.Net.Security.SecureChannel.GenerateToken(Byte[] input, Int32 offset, Int32 count, Byte[]& output)
   at System.Net.Security.SecureChannel.NextMessage(Byte[] incoming, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ForceAuthentication(Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
   at System.Net.TlsStream.CallProcessAuthentication(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Net.TlsStream.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult result)
   at System.Net.TlsStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.Net.PooledStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.Net.ConnectStream.WriteHeaders(Boolean async)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
```

Comment: Just because you've got TLS 1.2 doesn't mean the servers have the same crypto algorithms enabled. You can use [IIS Crypto](https://www.nartac.com/Products/IISCrypto/) to see what algorithms your client has and potentially enable some more (just make sure you don't enable anything that's insecure).

Comment: Lat June Microsoft did a security push that disabled TLS 1.0 and 1.1 and SSL on servers.  So client must use TLS 1.2 or 1.3.   SecurityProtocol is a static method that just specifies version of TLS to use.  Remove 1.1.  You error message indicates you are using Net for TLS.  It is recommended to Use Operating System for TLS w hich is the default inNet 4.7.2 or later.  Net does not support all the encryption modes for TLS so it is better to use Operating System.

Comment: gotcha.. server has v4.8 and my app has v4.5. after changing to v4.8 it works fine. for similar in QA server has v4.8 but my code with v4.5 works fine. I don't what the difference.

Answer (score 0):

It seems part of your exception message is missing but I found [this article that might help you.](https://www.ryadel.com/en/asp-net-client-server-cannot-comunicate-because-they-possess-common-algorithm-how-to-fix-c-sharp/)

> Such kind of error message usually occurs when the website is not able to match the cryptographic protocol(s) available to the other endpoint

It prescribes a few steps you could follow to try to resolve this. Hopefully it solves your problem.

You'll have to refine the steps depending on which version of .NET and other dependencies that you have on the machine.

Comment: gotcha.. server has v4.8 and my app has v4.5. after changing to v4.8 it works fine. for similar in QA server has v4.8 but my code with v4.5 works fine. I don't what the difference.